# Qual è il significato di "alle prese" in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Questa frase appartiene al racconto  *Il conte di Montecristo* di Italo Calvino:

> Ormai non so più se quello che sento scavare come una talpa è il vero Faria che apre brecce nelle mura della vera fortezza d'If o è l'ipotesi di un Faria *alle prese* d'una fortezza ipotetica.

Non capisco molto bene il significato dell'espressione "alle prese" in questa frase. Nel [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/presa/) ho trovato questa accezione:

> Con riferimento al sign. che il termine ha nella lotta, l’espressione dell’uso com. *venire alle prese* (propriam., degli avversarî che iniziano la lotta afferrandosi l’uno all’altro), venire a contesa, anche di parole; con sign. più generico, *essere alle p. con*, essere impegnato in qualche cosa di difficile, di complicato: *lo trovai alle prese con la dichiarazione dei redditi*.

Significa questo che questo personaggio, l'abate Faria, sta in certo modo lottando contro la fortezza d'If? Questo Faria, come nel romanzo di Alexandre Dumas,  è un prigionero della fortezza che da anni cerca di evadersi senza riuscirne.

Comment: Esatto. "Essere alla prese con X" significa "lottare contro X", oppure (per estensione, se X non è un soggetto senziente) "essere duramente impegnati contro X".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buon giorno.

Non conosco la storia, quindi mi baso sul brano che hai copiato all'inizio e quello che hai detto alla fine.

L'abate Faria sta scavando per aprire un passaggio nelle mura da cui vuole scavare. Questo è quello che dice all'inizio. Ovviamente, scavando fa un rumore che l'abate stesso sente. Quindi l'abate è "alle prese" con una vera fortezza da cui cerca di scappare.

Alla fine della frase "alle prese d'una fortezza ipotetica" fa un confronto: è come se nella testa del nostro abate ci sia un'altra fortezza (probabilmente l'idea di fuggire, di essere prigioniero e voler ottenere la libertà, ... non posso dire molto su questo perché dovrei conoscere la storia) in cui lui sta "scavando" per raggiungere un obiettivo. Come nel mondo reale, anche questo scavare nella sua testa produce "un rumore" (interpreta come pensieri, preoccupazioni, idee, ...) al punto che non riesce più a distinguere tra lo scavare reale e quello all'interno della sua testa. Questo scavare nella testa è talmente reale per lui che è come se fosse "alle prese" con una seconda fortezza da cui vuole scappare.

Quindi, la definizione del vocabolario è esatta: solo che deve essere riportata ad un ambito figurato e non concreto, quindi alla fortezza che si trova nella testa dell'abate.

Spero di essere stato utile.